# Secure ASP.NET Web API for iOS Consumtion

Tags: ios, rest, asp.net-web-api

So I am trying to secure an ASP.NET Web API Service so that an iOS (iPhone 4/5) application can access it RESTfully using their Windows user name and password (don't ask :) ), and I have followed this [article here](http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-message-handlers/), and for the most part it works, I just modified it a little to use Active Directory Services to validate the user name and password, but I am wondering if there are better ways to secure a ASP.NET Web API that will be used from non-browser clients as well as browsers possibly?

This is hosted with IIS7, so should I just let IIS control the authentication?

Need a little guidance... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear specifically what you are looking for, in my experience assuming I'm authenticating against a server the keys were

- Put access to the APIs behind https
- Send the request via POST.

If you're also coding the iOS side, make sure you are implementing authentication challenging properly.  Here's an article on the iOS side: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/networking/handling-url-authentication-challenges-accessing-password-protected-servers.html

Comment: I cannot stress enough how important it is that you use HTTPS here. BasicAuth encodes the user's credentials in Base64 and attaches it to every request. This means that anyone watching the network can easily recover their AD credentials.

Comment: @RobNapier - I would be using SSL/TLS for sure. Do you think it is secure enough using SSL? I mean we trust our credit card #'s and personal info over SSL, so why not my AD account right?

Comment: It's preferable to use tokens (such as via Kerberos) or challenge-response systems for authentication (NTLMv2 for instance), so that you don't have to mess with sending raw credentials, but with properly configured HTTPS, including certificate verification, it's pretty good. One reason that raw credentials are still a bit dangerous is that the admin of the web server has access to the post-SSL traffic. With a challenge-response system, that doesn't expose the password to him. So I don't like BasicAuth, but it can be made "ok" with HTTPS.

Comment: @RobNapier - Do you have any suggestions or links to samples of securing RESTFul Web Services that are consumed by multiple clients (iOS, Java, .NET, Web Browsers)?